# I want to get multiple documents from specific collection in firestore and store it in array so that I can access that data in my page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have named the Firestore collection the id from my local storage. I then want to get all the document and their data from the collection to show it on my page. I am using the following code; my main problem is that I can't keep the data in the array from useState and call the data in useEffect.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {FaArrowCircleUp} from 'react-icons/fa'
import {collection,getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../../config/firebase'

function Lobby() {
  const [getData, setGetData] =useState([])

  const data = async() =>{
    const docData = await getDocs(collection(db, localStorage.getItem("uid")))
    docData.forEach((item) =>{
      setGetData([...getData, {docName:item.id, dateModified: item.data().dateModified.toDate()}])
    })
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    data()
    console.log(getData)
  },[])

  return (
    <div className='lobby'>
      <h1>YOUR WORK</h1>
      <div className="table">
        <div className="table-section">
           <p> Title</p>
           <span>
           <FaArrowCircleUp />
           </span>
        </div>
        <div className="  table-section">
          <p>Last Edited</p>
          <span>
           <FaArrowCircleUp />
           </span>
        </div>
        <div className="  table-section">
          <p>Others</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Lobby
```

when I do this the array only stores the last document. I have 3 documents but it only stores the last. And if I dont put any dependency than it wont even store a value and if i put getItem than it keeps on adding only the last document.

Comment: TL;DR use `setGetData(docData.docs.map((doc) => ({docName: doc.id, dateModified: doc.data().dateModified.toDate()})))`. No `forEach` required

Comment: yeah the code worked but I still can't get the data because it isn't receiving the data when the page loads and when I add the dependency of getData it keeps on adding the data @Phil

Comment: `console.log(getData)` in your effect hook will never show the right data for multiple reasons. Why are you logging the data instead of just using it in your app? Add something like `<pre>getData = {JSON.stringify(getData)}</pre>` in your JSX if you just want to dump out the values or better still, use the [React Developer Tools](https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools) to inspect your component state

Comment: @Phil It is still taking multiple data. It loads atleast 2 times and outputs the value ranging from 2-4 times

Comment: That would be because of `<StrictMode>` but if you're using the `map()` code from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277641/i-want-to-get-multiple-documents-from-specific-collection-in-firestore-and-store?noredirect=1#comment136235581_77277641), that shouldn't matter